# melodic "CMake Error at /usr/src/googletest/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake:149" - Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening.

I am getting mad :  I developed a ROS package which compiles perfectly under a first laptop, and which has configuring errors on a second one with nearly the same system.  Both laptop run Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (in fact XUbuntu) with ros-melodic (from packages.ROS.org) .

The first one has desktop-full version 1.4.1-0bionic.20210415.004555, while the second has version 1.4.1-0bionic.20210415.025752.  But Synaptic claims that this is the last version for both!

The complete error on the second is :

`...

-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built

CMake Error at /usr/src/googletest/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake:149 (add_library):

  add_library cannot create target "gmock" because another target with the

  same name already exists.  The existing target is a shared library created

  in source directory "/usr/src/googletest/googlemock".  See documentation

  for policy CMP0002 for more details.

Call Stack (most recent call first):

  /usr/src/googletest/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake:172 (cxx_library_with_type)

  /usr/src/gmock/CMakeLists.txt:84 (cxx_library)



(repeated twice)

...

-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also ".../ROS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

See also ".../ROS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Makefile:808: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed

make[1]: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1

make[1] : ...

Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed`

Neither .../ROS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log nor See also .../ROS/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log seem to contain any interesting line.

Here are the CMakeList.txt and the package.xml :

`### CMake #################################################################

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)

project(qt_ctrl)



### Catkin ################################################################



add_compile_options(-std=c++11)



find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS qt_build roscpp nav_msgs)



include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} include ISeeML/include)<br>
<br>
catkin_package() <br>
<br>
### Qt Environment ########################################################<br>
<br>
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets)<br>
<br>
### ISeeML Library ########################################################<br>
<br>
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ISeeML/build/linux)



### Sections ##############################################################



file(GLOB QT_RESOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} resources.qrc)<br>
file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_MOC RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
  FOLLOW_SYMLINKS include/*/*.hpp)



set(QT_LIBRARIES Qt5::Widgets)

qt5_add_resources(QT_RESOURCES_CPP ${QT_RESOURCES})<br>
qt5_wrap_cpp(QT_MOC_HPP ${QT_MOC})



### Sources ###############################################################



file(GLOB_RECURSE QT_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
  FOLLOW_SYMLINKS src/*/*.cpp)<br>
<br>
### Binaries ##############################################################<br>
<br>
add_executable(gui ${QT_SOURCES} ${QT_RESOURCES_CPP} ${QT_FORMS_HPP}
  ${QT_MOC_HPP})<br>
<br>
target_link_libraries(gui ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} CompISeeML)`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>qt_ctrl</name>
  <version>0.2.1</version>
  <description>
    The ROS package qt_ctrl aims at proposing several controllers 
    for ROS with Qt GUI, in order to compare them.
  </description>
  <maintainer email="Alexis.Scheuer@loria.fr">Alexis Scheuer</maintainer>
  <author>Alexis Scheuer
  <license>GPLv3

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>qt_build</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>

  <run_depend>qt_build</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>nav_msgs</run_depend>

</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391860/melodic-%22cmake-error-at-/usr/src/googletest/googletest/cmake/internal_utils.cmake:149%22---invoking-%22make-cmake_check_build_system%22-failed/) by [AlexisScheuer](https://answers.ros.org/users/90599/alexisscheuer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-11-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-29**:
Try the following work around, in source directory `/usr/src/gtest`, open `CMakelists.txt` comment out the following using #:

```
# cxx_library(gtest "${cxx+strict}" src/gtest-all.cc)
# cxx_library(gtest_main "${cxx_strict}" src/gtest_main.cc)
# target_link_libraries(gtest_main gtest)
```

It's not a solution to the error but it won't affect the performance of your package either. Most likely another package is already calling gtest and it's creating the conflict. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085151/cmake-conflict-with-multiple-gtest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered that my second laptop (not compiling) had a /usr/src/gtest directory (I don't know why) while the other one had a symbolic link from /usr/src/gtest to /usr/src/googletest/googletest.  I did the same (saving the old gtest in an archive), and this solved everything!..

---

Originally posted by [AlexisScheuer](https://answers.ros.org/users/90599/alexisscheuer/) with karma: 26 on 2021-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-02**:
Glad you found the solution :)